# Pytube age restricted, and can't be accessed without logging in

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying download a video from YouTube by pytube but it throws this error below:

```
url_youtube age restricted, and can't be accessed without logging in.
```

Some posts says to open pytube -> innertube.py and change the line 223:

```py
def __init__(self, client='ANDROID_MUSIC', use_oauth=False, allow_cache=True)
```

to:

```py
def __init__(self, client='ANDROID', use_oauth=False, allow_cache=True)
```

I did it but throws another error:

```
HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.
```

What can I do?